# convert an array into formatted query param

Tags: php, param

I am having an array in php as below

```
Array
(
    [0] => 375452292
    [1] => 205304629
    [2] => 910337332
    [3] => 616516330
    [4] => 560488951
)
```

i am trying to convert this array into a formatted query parameter as below

```
'375452292','205304629','910337332','616516330','560488951'
```

pls help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "implode"

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

```
implode(",", $array);
```